# Clojure's Cheshire JSON API not reading entire JSON file

Tags: clojure

I have JSON data in the following format:

```
{"load":{"meta": 12345}}
{"load":{"meta": 54321}}
...
```

When I attempt to load the data with Cheshire I get back only the first line of data translated into edn:

```
(def read-json-data (parse-string (slurp "data/json_data") true))

=> {:load {:meta 12345}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is correct behaviour - `cheshire/parse-string` parses the first JSON object it can find.

If you want the whole file to be parsed as a single JSON object you should make an array:

```
[{"load": {"meta": 12345}},
 {"load": {"meta": 54321}},
 ...]
```

Alternatively, if you want to parse each line separately you can do something like this:

```
(map #(cheshire/parse-string % true)
     (line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader "data/json_data")))
```

(Also, notice the colons in the JSON.)

Comment: Cheshire now has a `parse-stream` function so I used something like this in my code and it worked: `(-> r clojure.java.io/reader cheshire/parse-stream)`.

Comment: @AmirEldor `parse-stream` is not appropriate here. The function from @bsvingen is still the way to do things.

Comment: Hello @Casey. It's been quite a while since I touched Clojure and I'm no expert but I believe I took my example from cheshire's docs: `(parse-stream (clojure.java.io/reader "/tmp/foo"))` which is on their main page. If I mixed up something somehow it would be nice to know. I guess the answer to the OP would be more appropriate with parse-string but as for reading a file, I think what cheshire suggests is a good way.